# Stuck at GRUB command line after installation on Dell 5558

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, usb, uefi

I have Dell 5558 laptop with Windows 8.1 pre-installed. I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows, so I downloaded the iso image. I then formatted my pendrive then using universal USB Installer I copied it to my USB and made it bootable. But after restarting I get `grub>` command line screen when I try to boot through my pendrive.

I dont know how to proceed afterwards. I have tried using `ls` command to find all directories, I get `hd0 hd1 hd2 hd2,gpt1..7,hd3`. But when I try to access them it shows undefined directory. `hd2,gpt1` and `hd2,gpt2` have some folders like `Windows/` `Boot/` `Efi`. In the `Boot/` folder there is a file named `boot.efi.(something)`. I dont remember exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your USB drive needs to be formatted as FAT32

2) I found https://rufus.akeo.ie/ to be very reliable for UEFI (recent, > 2009) systems (this may not be the case with universal USB installer)

Answer (score 0):

I have checked some Dell Manuals and I guess there should be something wrong with your USB Installer or ISO Image and you should try to format your USB as FAT32

Answer (score 0):

Tools to create bootable USB drives from `.iso` files are not created equal. I'm not very familiar with the one you mention, so I can't comment on it specifically; but as a general rule, if you run into problems like those you describe, one of the first things (perhaps *the* first thing) I recommend doing is re-creating the USB drive with another tool. I generally use `dd` in Linux to make the drive; but [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) (as Smile4ever recommends) and [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/) both seem to work pretty well. Even they might fail sometimes, though; unfortunately, some computers are just plain finicky, and if a disk isn't *exactly* to the firmware's liking, it might not boot or might exhibit other problems.